# How reclaim pdf file type from FoxitReader?

Tags: pdf, mime-types, thunar, file-types

I installed FoxitReader. Now when I look at the detailed listing in my file browser (Thunar), it displays the filetype of any pdf as 'FoxitReader document'.

How do I get it to display simply as PDF?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. The following solution worked for me. I went to the folder `~/.local/share/mime/`, and here I deleted the files `./application/pdf.xml`, `./application/ppdf.xml`, and `./packages/FoxitReader.xml`. I also deleted the lines in the file `./types` reading `application/pdf` and `application/ppdf`. (I'm not sure which of these was necessary.) Logged out and logged in. Now PDF documents are shown as "PDF document".

Comment: relief! -- what though are the 'relevant files' you deleted? and what are the 'relevant lines' you removed? And what reason do you have for taking these specific steps? And after you've done this and logged back in, what relevant lines + files should remain/reappear? Your solution might suggest deleting+removing all pdf+ppdf.xml files, + removing the application/pdf + application/ppdf lines from ./types. But I wnat to be careful about deleting sys files, and I wonder how then can it work at all all pdf references have been deleted?

Comment: First of all, these are not system files, but config files, so you cannot really break your system by deleting those. But if you are really worried you can create some backup files (this is the usual practice if you are really messing with system files).
I don't really remember why I took these exact steps. I knew that I had to look for some files in my home folder because the phenomenon showed up already when I copied my files from my previous computer. 
Finally, "relevant files"=files whose name contain "pdf", "relevant lines"=lines which contain the string "pdf".

Comment: thx again, Iras. I hope you will update yr answr 2b clear about what files + lines shdb deleted to solve the prob.

Comment: Done. I hope it is clear now.